# How to find the reason why kafka broker got down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We are using kafka version 2.11-0.11.0.2 and zookeeper version 3.3.6.
And they are they are running on Ubuntu 16.0.4.

We are producing data with rate of 3k messages per second and the size of each message is around 150 Bytes. we have 7 brokers and 1 zookeeper, and sometimes some of brokers get down.

So how we can find out the reason that why a particular broker was got down? And where the broker stop logs are stored from where we can check the logs and can find why it was stopped?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to start a Kafka broker using

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

the errors will be reported in the terminal.

If you are running multiple brokers I'd suggest to store run the processes in the background and store the output in a file. For example,

```
nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties >> server1.out 2>&1 &
```

will start the broker and store output of the process to `server1.out`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But we have started kafka broker by following command -
nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
So  we don't have output file.
So now it is possible to find the reason without server.out file ?

Comment: If you haven't defined an output file, then `nohup.out` is automatically generated. You should be able to find the errors in that file.

Comment: Ok. But Sir , can we define a config in log4j so it can store only startup and stop log details?

Comment: I am not aware of any such configuration. You can search for `ERROR` in the output files instead.

Comment: Yes, I was searchng ERROR in that file. But its size was too large So it was taking time. Still it is searching. Lets see what happens

Comment: `more nohup.out | grep ERROR`

Comment: Actually I was searching with following command -
grep -rnw 'nohup.out' -e 'ERROR'
It was taking too much time , now let me try with 
more nohup.out | grep ERROR